# jquery check what changed in a form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to check if any data in a form has been changed by a user, either removed, added or modified in any way and send the data to PHP so that I only have to execute specific update commands instead of updating everything. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: When the form is submitted or when the data actually changes in an input?

Comment: when the form is submitted

Comment: In order to check if there is a change you're going to have to query the database and then compare what is submitted to determine if there is a change and then perform the update accordingly.

Comment: why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: because data on a page is taken from multiple tables. I don't want to run 10 update statements if only 1 table needs to be updated.

Comment: My guess is you will have more logic code involved in trying to figure out which updates do need to be done vs just doing the updates. That being said you can always store a serialized version of form once page loads and compare prior to submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First decide do you need to check updated data in client side or server side.

If you check updated data in client side, you will prevent submit unwanted data and submit will be quick. 
To achieve this, when you submitting form before submit, in following js method check which data has changed. First in document ready function, create hidden variables or global js variables and assign initial values of form. Then in following method check current form values with those variables values. Then you can identified which data has been changed. Then from form remove existing values.( You may be need to aware of mandatory fields when remove data).

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    // Put code here.
});
```

If you are planning to check data in server side, you can place logic in server side and prevent be messing client side code and store heavy data. To achieve this you have to do extra database call. After get data from form, in server side do extra db call which use to initially load data to form and check what are the changed data and then save only updated data.